# ASP.NET date formatting issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a SQL Server database which has a column of date with value of `2001-12-23`. The insert statement makes sure that the input is correctly formatted using the following code:

```
var start_date_formatted = DateTime.ParseExact(start_date.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Even though the input is formatted as `dd-MM-yyyy` it still appears in the database as `2001-12-23`.

The thing that I don't understand is the fact that whenever I query the data from the database, it returns the date correctly formatted `dd-MM-yyyy` even though it appears in the database as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

That is not a big deal since I got the formatting I need eventually.

The problem is that the time string is being added to my date generating the output of `23-12-2001 00:00:00`. I need date only but can't figure out why is it being added and why can't I change it using the following method:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "dd-MM-YYYY", null); // string is not recognized as valid DateTime
```

or

```
.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY"); // no overload method ToString that takes 1 argument
```

Since I'm new to asp.net I would like to get to know how to handle date formats and if there is any general config setting which would require and set certain date format?

UPDATE

```
var dt = BookingAccess.ManageBookingsDataTable();
            string id = string.Empty;
            string name = string.Empty;
            string startdate = string.Empty;
            string enddate = string.Empty;
            string full_string = string.Empty;
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    id = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                    var sdate = dt.Rows[i]["start_date"];
                    name = dt.Rows[i]["Pet name"].ToString();
                    startdate = dt.Rows[i]["start_date"].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // error is thrown here
                    enddate = dt.Rows[i]["end_date"].ToString();
                    full_string = startdate + " to " + enddate + " (" + name + ")";
                    CurrentBookings.Items.Add(new ListItem(full_string, id));
                }
            }
```

This does not seem to format the date either:

```
startdate = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt.Rows[i]["start_date"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# there is no Type Date, so all dates is variables of DateTime type. So when you get date from db it transfers into DateTime variable with time 00:00:00

To get string from this you can use `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
string dateinstring = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")); //it contains "23-11-2012"
```

**Update:**

Your problem is that your datatable is not typed, so your startdate is object, not DateTime. You should cast it to DateTime:

```
startdate = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["start_date"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This will works if your `dt.Rows[i]["start_date"]` is not nullable, in other case you should check that it is not null before casting.

Comment: I used ToString method but ut returns error that there is no method that takes 1 argument

Comment: Could you show not working code? I'm test my code (that is in my answer) right now and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't worry about the display format of a DateTime in SQL Server. In my SQL management studio they also appear as 2001-12-23, but in my Visual Studio as 23-12-2001.

You probably set the Column Data Type to `DateTime`. This adds a time of 00:00:00, if none specified. You can specify the `Date` type if you only want to store a date, although it doesn't really matter if you format the `DateTime` on your website.

--

Update:

Cast the value from the database to a DateTime, then format it:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["start_date"]); 
string startdate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: I checked again and my column has a type of date which I assume should prevent the time string to even be taken under consideration when inserting and/or retrieving data from database

Comment: What database designer do you use?

Comment: Nothing special, I use generic MS SQL Management Studio to create and manage my database

Comment: A column with data type `Date` doesn't show a time for me in MS SQL Server Management Studio. Are sure it's a `Date` column?

Comment: DataType = date The thing is that I used to have the same problem in my DataGrid table and I solved it the following way DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" But I also need to be able to apply this rule to the dates being managed trough the code behind file

Comment: If you work with `DateTime` objects in your code-behind, you should have no problems.

Comment: apparently this returns no errors but does not format the date...'startdate = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt.Rows[i]["start_date"].ToString());'

Comment: Try `DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["start_date"]);  string dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` Or you could use `date.ToShortDateString()` but that might give some culture issues.